# Question about ratio word problem

Tags: word-problem, ratio

Here is the question and solutions: [image]

It is possible that there are 10 cups of peanuts, 6 cups of walnuts, 4 cups of cashews. So total number of cups in this mix is 20. So 10:6:4 can be reduced to 5:3:2.
Another combination of the mix could be 20 cups of peanuts, 12 cups of walnuts, and 8 cups of cashews. So the total number of cups in this mix is 20+12 +8= 40  So 20:12:8 could be reduced to 5:3:2.

So I do not know how many cups of party mix based on the ratio 5:3:2 as this ratio could be reduced.

Without know how many cups of party mix, how is the answer between 3 and 4?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: You need $3$ cups of walnuts to make $10$ cups $(5 + 3 + 2)$ of party mix. Then how many cups of walnuts do you need to make $12$ cups of party mix?

Comment: It is told that you need to make $12$ cups of party mix

Comment: So the number of walnuts required is  $\frac{3}{5+3+2} * 12 = 3.6$

Comment: Why is the number of cups = 5+3+2 for the original party mix? It is possible that there are 10 cups of peanuts, 6 cups of walnuts, 4 cups of cashews. So total number of cups in this case is 10+6+4 = 20. This combination also has a ratio of 5:3:2.  You see my point. The ratio 5:3:2 does not tell you the number of cups. Thanks!

Comment: $5+3+2=10$  so if you make $10$ cups of party mix, you will use $5$ cups of peanuts, $3$ of walnuts $2$ of cashews.  If you make $12$ cups of party mix, you need $20\%$ more of each ingredient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says you are making $12$ cups of party mix.  All the quantities in $5:3:2$ need to be multiplied by $\frac{12}{10}$

Comment: Thanks Ross. However, Why is the number of cups = 5+3+2 for the original party mix? It is possible that there are 10 cups of peanuts, 6 cups of walnuts, 4 cups of cashews. So total number of cups in this case is 10+6+4 = 20. It also a ratio of 5:3:2.  You see my point. The ratio 5:3:2 does not tell you the number of cups. Thanks!

Comment: To make any volume $V$ you need $\frac 5{5+3+2}V$ of peanuts, $\frac 3{5+3+2}V$ of walnuts, and $\frac 2{5+3+2}V$ of cashews.  The ratio does tell you how many cups it makes if you make one recipe, which is just the sum of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, consider "per cup of party mix", you need exactly $0.5$ cups of peanuts, $0.3$ cups of walnuts, $0.2$ cups of cashews -- does this make sense? Irrespective of number of total cups of mix made. I'd say we "norm" the ratios to have the sum of $1$.
So you only need to multiply $0.3$ by $12$ to get the desired result.